# Lt. Joe Kenda's expertise(?) in fundamental physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, projectile

I may have gotten confused due to advanced age, but I heard Joe Kenda on the TV show "Homicide Hunter" make a statement that left me befuddled and in doubt. Of course, the lieutenant has vast experience regarding shootings. Paraphrasing, he said,

> "It's not at all like you see in the movies where a person gets shot and flies backward. Every action has an equal and opposite reaction. When shot in the front, the victim either falls forward (toward the shooter) or simply crumples straight down to the floor".

That can't be right, can it? Say you're in a canoe, just offshore, dead still in the water, and someone onshore tosses you a heavy object (eg the proverbial medicine ball) and you catch it. Your canoe will start moving away from shore, naturally. So, similarly, when your body catches a bullet you tend to fall back. Who is right?

Comment: The statement has truth in it but the explanation is totally unclear. Let's take another case where momentum is instantly imparted, suppose you hit a baseball with a baseball bat. The physics is similar in sense that you have a high speed object hitting a relatively low speed one. What happens? The ball gets shot off far. Now you can imagine that whole situation is happen in reverse to get the ball hitting bat effect, clearly you would see that the ball will not move the bat much.

Comment: The statement is utter rubbish. Momentum conservation causes the center of mass of the victim to move (very little) backward, away from the shooter. Angular momentum transfer could, in principle, cause the victim to **rotate** towards the shooter (with his center of mass still moving backward!), but only if the victim is hit below his center of mass and the exerted force is enough to surmount friction of his feet on the ground (which I highly doubt). Finally, since the victim's body is not rigid, there will be some bending in the upper and lower half of the body, which is nothing but inertia,

Comment: and so there is still no movement toward the shooter. According to real forensic experts I have seen on a true crime series, the most likely scenario is that the body will just fall straight to the ground, especially if hit in the head with instant death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While bullets travel fast, they are extremely light compared to the mass of the human body, so they barely cause any backward motion on the victim.

Let's do the math. Consider a $80\text{ kg}$ target being shot with a .44 bullet weighing $16\text{ g}$ and traveling at $360\text{ m/s}$. Realistically the bullet will likely pass right through the victim, imparting only a fraction of its momentum. But consider the unlikely scenario where the bullet becomes embedded in the victim (or their ballistic vest) in a perfectly inelastic collision, resulting in the highest possible momentum transfer. The victim now moves backward with the same momentum as that of the bullet, yielding a speed of
$$\frac{16\text{ g }\times 360 \text{ m/s}}{80\text{ kg}}=7.2\text{ cm/s}.$$
Compare this with a typical walking speed, which is usually greater than $100\text{ cm/s}.$

Answer (score 1):

As to the observation that people tends to slump forward when they've been shot.

When a person is standing upright most of of the weight of that person is carried by the [forefeet](https://ankleandfootcentre.com.au/forefoot/).

You can try that as follows. Find some sort of ledge, for example the bottom step of stairs. Stand upright, with the forefoot extended over the ledge. That way the forward half of your feet aren't carrying the portion of your weight that they are normally carrying.

Your center of mass is still above the ledge, you can prevent yourself from tipping forward, but it feels *very uncomfortable*. It feels so awkward because in normal circumstances the forefoot is carrying more than half of your weight, that is the normal weigth distribution along the length of your feet.

When a person is suddenly incapacitated all the muscles go limp. The calf muscles are active in enabling the forefoot to carry weight. So when all muscles go limp the person will crumple to the ground, or fall forward.

As pointed out in the answer by contributor @Puk, there is some momentum transfer from the bullet, but nowhere near enough to make a difference.